# how to get customer group from subscriber magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

As you know, in database, newsletter_subscriber table have customer_id column

In admin newsletter subscriber grid, i add column Customer Group like this

```
    $this->addColumn('customer_group', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Customer Group'),
        'index'     => 'customer_group'

    ));
```

So how can get customer group from customer_id in subscriber?

thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify last lines in `protected function _prepareCollection()` method

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('ce'=>'customer_entity'),'ce.entity_id=main_table.customer_id',array('ce.group_id'));
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('cg'=>'customer_group'),'cg.customer_group_id=ce.group_id',array('cg.customer_group_code'));
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

and then add field like this

```
 $this->addColumn('customer_group_code', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Customer Group'),
        'index'     => 'customer_group_code'
    ));
```